# ¿Cómo validan una inserción o una selección de datos en PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo esta inquietud de hace un rato ya que yo valido con `mysqli_num_rows` y me arroja errores casi siempre, aunque siempre lo resuelvo, pero quisiera saber de que otra forma se puede hacer esto.

```
public function AgregarNewAlbum(){

    $acciones = 0;
    $estado  = false;
    $mensaje = "Inciando...";
    $contenido = "";


    if($_POST){
        //INCLUIMOS EL SCRIPT DE CONEXION E INSTANCIAMOS UN OBJETO DE CONEXION
        include_once 'modelo/class.Conexion.php';
        $db = new Conexion();


        $nombreAlbum = $_POST['newAlbum'];
        $descripcionAlbum = $_POST['descripcionAlbum'];
        //ISERTAMOS UN NEW ALBUM
        $sql =  $db->query("INSERT INTO albunes(nombre_album, descripcion_album)VALUES('".$nombreAlbum."','".$descripcionAlbum."')");
        if(!mysql_error()){

            if($wa = $db->rows($sql)>0){
                echo var_dump($wa);
                $acciones = 1;
                $estado = true;
                $mensaje = "<label class='suscces'>NUEVO ALBUM AGREGADO CORRECTAMENTE</label>";

                $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM albunes");

                $contenido .='<option>Seleccione Album</option>';

                while($rew = $db->recorrer($sql)){
                    $contenido .= "<option value='".$rew['id_album']."'>".$rew['nombre_album']."</option>";
                }

            //$salidaJson = array("contenido" => $contenido);
            }else{
                $accion = 0;
                $estado = false;
                $mensaje = "<label class='error'>NO SE PUDO AGREGAR EL NUEVO ALBUM</label>";

            }


        }else{
            $acciones = 0;
            $estado = false;
            $mensaje = "ERROR,NO SE HA PODIDO AGREGAR EL NUEVO ALBUM ".mysql_error().' - '.mysql_errno();
        }

    }else{

       $mensaje = "NO EXISTEN VARIABLES POST"; 
    }



    $salidaJson = array("respuesta" => $estado,
                "mensaje" => $mensaje,
                "contenido" => $contenido,
                "acciones" => $acciones);

    echo json_encode($salidaJson);
}
´
```

Esto me genera el siguiente error:

> **Warning**:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in **C:\dagg\htdocs\escuelanevada\Intranet\modelo\class.Conexion.php** on line **13**
> {"respuesta":false,"mensaje":"NO SE PUDO AGREGAR EL NUEVO ALBUM</label>","contenido":"","acciones":0}"

Pero se inserta perfectamente el nuevo álbum, ¿qué será?

Comment: Seria bueno si incluyeras el código de 'modelo/class.Conexion.php' ya que el error te esta dando en ese archivo y no en el código que pasaste.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que sucede es que la consulta que estás ejecutando arroja errores. eso hace que el resultado de `mysqli_query` (o mysqli::query si usas el api OOP) no retorne un `mysqli_result` sino `boolean`.

Debes validar el resultado de la consulta, es decir:

```
$resultado =  $db->query("INSERT INTO ...");        

if (! $resultado ) {
     // este error lo puedes obtener usando 
     // mysqli_error($db) o $db->error;
     return "Error no inserto, ";  
} else {
    $lastID = $db->insert_id; // o mysqli_insert_id($db);
    return "Ultimo ID insertado es {$lastID}"; 
}
```

El manejo de errores es a tu gusto, es recomendable usar excepciones.

Answer (score 0):

No hace que falta que vuelvas a comprobar la inserción con `$wa = $db->rows($sql)>0`. En mysqli la función query retorna `TRUE` si estás haciendo un `INSERT` y ha ido bien.

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

Tomando de referencia la respuesta: 
[Mysqli always return true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194442/mysqli-query-always-return-true)

y para ampliar la respuesta de [Ariel Andres Navarrete Garcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16618/ariel-andres-navarrete-garcia), `msqli_query()` responde `TRUE`siempre que sea un query que no falle; es decir, no depende de que retorne resultados o no.

Dicho esto, la manera adecuada de validar `mysqli_query()` seria con un `or die(mysqli_error())`. y ya luego puedes comprobar el count de lo que te retorne con `mysqli_num_rows()`.